# Azure Functions concurrency: maxConcurrentRequests - is it Truly parallel to give a simultaneous execution of all requests happening at the same time

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Here in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163971/6514559 it is explained that

1. If Azure decides that your App needs to scale and creates a new
   host, and say there are two hosts, then values of these params (`maxConcurrentRequests` ,`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT`) are
   applied per host not across host.
2. If your App has multiple Functions
   then maxConcurrentRequests applies to-all/across Functions within
   this host, not per Function.

The questions are,

- Is it possible to have more than one function app on a single host
  (Is this what is controlled by `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT`?)
- `maxConcurrentRequests = 100`  does this really means that all
  100 requests will be processed in parallel (simultaneously) by a single host
  (Consumption plan , 1 CPU,1.5GB Host ) . [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/142850/azure-functions-concurrency-test.html) thread here suspects everything is executed in series?!

since each instance of the Functions host in the Consumption plan is limited to 1.5 GB of memory and one CPU ([Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5af3c567-de36-4963-b4e3-fddae5749cf8/scaling-out?forum=AzureFunctions)), how can it run parallel loads with one CPU? On a different thought [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) does say ACU per instance is 100 for Consumption Plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66819426/496289), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893060/496289) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits). And OP already read it, but [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163971/496289) for completeness.

> Is it possible to have more than one function app on a single host

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling) is very confusing. AFAIK:

- On consumption plan, no.
- On premium/app-service plan, [there is a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#organize-functions-for-performance-and-scaling) hint that might mean relation is one host to many apps, but IMO it's debatable.

> (Is this what is controlled by FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT?)

NO.

Need to understand the terms:

- **Function App**: One Function App. Top level Azure Resource. A logical collection of Functions.
- **Function**: One Function with in/out-trigger/binding(s). One Function App contains one or more Functions.
- **Function Host**: Virtual/physical host where Function App runs as Linux/Windows process.
- **Worker Process**: One process (one pid) running on a Function Host.

  - One Worker Process hosts all Functions of one Function App.
  - One Host will have `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` (default 1) Worker Processes running on it, sharing all resources (RAM, CPU, ..)

> maxConcurrentRequests = 100 does this really means that all 100 requests will be processed in parallel (simultaneously) by a single host (Consumption plan , 1 CPU,1.5GB Host ) .

[Discounting cold start problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893060/496289), execution would be in parallel [within limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits) of selected plan.

> This thread here suspects everything is executed in series?!

I'm sure there is an explanation. There is [unambiguous documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#configure-host-behaviors-to-better-handle-concurrency) that says requests do get executed in parallel, within limits.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. My thoughts on FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT was more like a virtual scenario, like multiple workers means => multiple pids of same function app . This may be indicative of the possibility to run multiple pids of different function apps.